# Solaris ZFS dataset delegated to a Zone is not mounted after server (or zone) reboot

Tags: solaris, zfs, zones

We have Solaris11 Express server with Zones
A Zone delegated ZFS dataset is not remounted after Zone or Server reboot.
(**mountpoint** property is set on ZFS dataset)
What can be missing in ZFS or Zone configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the logs for svc:/system/filesystem/local:default inside the zone, which should be /var/svc/log/system-filesystem-local:default.log (verify with 'svcs -l filesystem/local').  It might be some sort of conflict with the mountpoint (directory not empty or some such).  Any output from an attempt to mount that filesystem should be in the log.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the service svc:/system/filesystem/local wasn't running. Previously we updated the server with pkg-update, but the zones weren't updated. Once I updated the zones also, the problem was gone.

Comment: Yes, I think best-practice on ipkg systems (OpenIndiana and Sol 11 Express) is to shut down and detach zones during a beadm update.  After booting into the new BE, you use upgrade-on-attach to bring the zones up to date.